# Bootstrap table data row is enlarged

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, datatables

This error happens only in IE but I don't have any idea as I checked "developer tools" and saw nothing special.
[image]
[image]
When the page is load as the last cell can't hold "Launch Time", the row is expanded. However, if I click on top left "AWS Test VPC"(it sends the same request to web service and loads same data), the table is good now(Pic 2)

I'll attach the code if needed. Just don't know what's wrong

Comment: Your definition of crashing is ambiguous. Where is the description of the "crash?" It doesn't look like anything is crashing here.

Comment: @A.Sharma Sorry for misleading definition. I've updated the question. My question is that if you look at the two screenshot, you will see the row in pic1 is larger than pic2. When refreshing the page, pic1 happens. But if I click on top right text which sends a request to a web service using ajax, the row is fixed

Answer (score 0):

Have you try to add bootstrap class to the `th` in the table like below example.

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="col-xs-2">Col 1</th>
      <th class="col-xs-1">Col 2</th>
      <th class="col-xs-1">Col 3</th>
      <th class="col-xs-1">Col 4</th>
      <th class="col-xs-2">Col 5</th>
      <th class="col-xs-2">Col 6</th>
      <th class="col-xs-2">Col 7</th>
      <th class="col-xs-1">Col 8</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

This will resize the column to your desired size.